# Trigger event on a specific number of pixel counted from bottom of the page

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to trigger an event on the specific number of pixels counted from the bottom of the page with pure JavaScript.

For example, if the user scrolls 200px before the bottom, events need to be triggered.

The only thing which I succeed in is to trigger the event when the user scrolls to the bottom. I succeed that with the following code:

```
window.onscroll = () => {
    if ((window.innerHeight + Math.ceil(window.pageYOffset)) >= document.body.offsetHeight) {
        document.querySelector('.element').click();
    }
}
```

Probably there is a simple solution, but I'm a newbie with JS.

Comment: just subtract 200 from the document.body.offsetHeight

Answer (score 0):

Adapting your code is a simple matter:

```
window.onscroll = () => {
    if ((window.innerHeight + Math.ceil(window.pageYOffset)) >= document.body.offsetHeight-200) {
        document.querySelector('.element').click();
    }
}
```

however, I can see a problem - that will trigger *every time* a scroll happens that is in the right zone. so, scrolling from 200px to 199px, for example, will trigger a second click.

you can solve that by clearing the onscroll event at the end of the triggered code:

```
window.onscroll = () => {
    if ((window.innerHeight + Math.ceil(window.pageYOffset)) >= document.body.offsetHeight-200) {
        document.querySelector('.element').click();
        window.onscroll=null;
    }
}
```

A better approach to event management is to use addEventListener. more complex, but it allows for multiple events on the same trigger type.

example with addEventListener:

```
var theTrigger=()=>{
 if ((window.innerHeight + Math.ceil(window.pageYOffset)) >= document.body.offsetHeight-200) {
  document.querySelector('.element').click(); 
  window.removeEventListener('scroll', theTrigger);
 }
}
window.addEventListener('scroll', theTrigger);
```

note the "window.removeEventListener('scroll', theTrigger);" - if you really want it triggered on *every* scroll in the 200 range, then remove that line.

Comment: Yes, this works, but for some reason only once. Can you give me an example with addEventListener? I will try to implement it.

Comment: I've added an addEventListener example to the answer. note that I have not tested it. YMMV

Comment: Thank you for the effort. But it's not working for some reason.